# How can LiPo smartphone batteries keep working even after completely discharging them?

Tags: lipo

If LiPo batteries shouldn't be discharged below 3V, then how are we able to discharge the LIPo phone battery to almost zero, recharge it, and the battery still works?

Comment: Chances are "0%" on the phone does not equal "0%" charge on the battery.

Comment: Voted down for lack of own research: Vikrant [claims](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507429/how-can-lipo-smartphone-batteries-keep-working-even-after-completely-discharging/507432?noredirect=1#comment1298686_507432) wikipedia is blocked in his country, but then has very distinct [opinions why to not research on wikipedia](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/507429/how-can-lipo-smartphone-batteries-keep-working-even-after-completely-discharging#comment1299415_507432). We expect sufficient  engineer-level research.

Comment: @MarcusMüller again, Wikipedia is not a reliable source.please stop irritating users with his Wikipedia thing. And sometimes it is better to just ask the question in a forum, because sometimes you don't even know what to ask. I hope one day these forums will be free of obnoxious and ignorant people who just spread negativity and reduce the quality of interaction on forums like this.

Comment: @vikrant I haven't downvoted any other answer. Please be friendly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh my mistake. It is just a coincidence then. Although I must make it clear that I changed the accepted answer because the other one provides more value.

Comment: @vikrant absolutely not complaining about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the battery of course. Some batteries have protection circuits, some don't, some have short circuit protection, some expect it to be implemented on the device side (or drop it completely altogether).

We're talking about common Li-Po in consumer electronics. For clarity.

Yes, you can discharge some battery down to zero. I repair electronics and I meet batteries discharged to 1V or even lower with regular frequency in phones and laptops after water damage of the logic boards, specifically on main power lines. And yes, usually they can be carefully restored to operational voltages using small current (the charging circuit of the device won't charge it if it's deeply discharged). There is a little more under the hood tho.

No matter how you talk about it, you will eventually end up talking about chemistry. Yes, they can be restored to working condition usually, but there is no way to tell how much of capacity is going to be available. It will be usable, but I just don't make any promises about battery's health and longevity after its discharge trip. It's actually advised to replace the whole battery. After all, it's a consumable, it has a limited resource and it's something that's expected to be replaced during device's lifetime, even if manufacturers want you to think otherwise (hello Tim Apple).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completely support the right to repair movement.

Answer (score 5):

> How are we able to discharge the LIPo phone battery to almost zero,

We are *not* able to do that. The battery itself, but also the phone, has circuitry and software that shut down the phone before you deep-discharge the battery.

Comment: so if i remove the battery and somehow discharge it below 3v, it will be dead?

Comment: you will have to remove the battery, open it, remove the battery protection circuit, and then discharge it, but yes. That battery would be permanently damaged.

Comment: is the battery protection circuit needed of Lithium Ion batteries also?

Comment: I don't understand the question. LiPo batteries **are** lithium ion batteries. Yes, nothing is special about lithium-ion polymer batteries. Also, hint: wikipedia is a great source of information!

Comment: the reason i was confused between lipo and liion is because the websites selling them list them as different categories and rc drones almost always use lipo batteries.

Comment: All Li-Po batteries are Li-Ion, but not all Li-Ion batteries are Li-Po

Comment: again, all knowledge that is available via wikipedia!

Comment: wikipedia is banned in my country

Comment: That is terrible, and you should probably put more effort into getting rid of that ban than into asking questions here, because that ban puts you at a life-long disadvantage. For now, you should start using technologies like Tor to circumvent government censorship. Also, what terrible country is this? I would assume from your name that you're from India or Pakistan? I thought they didn't block wikipedia access. Or are you from Kashmir? I really don't like how Indian government is trying to suppress information getting out of there.

Comment: Anyway, wikipedia being blocked doesn't mean there's not millions of other sites that could have told you exactly this, so, it really doesn't make your question much better researched.

Comment: (Nepal, maybe? But I thought Internet was largely unfiltered there; the internet censorship observatory hasn't detected government blockage so far.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wikipedia is not a reliable source. Period. I hope you stop irritating other users of this wonderful forum with Wikipedia in future. You need to calm down and do yoga and meditation. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: lol, "wikipedia is not a reliable source" says the person who gets his basic information from third-party battery importer websites... And obviously, I'm not saying wikipedia should be your only source, but all your questions that you couldn't answer yourself can at least initially be answered using Wikipedia. Also, your comment betrays that you don't understand how this community works: we expect a high degree of own research, because this is electrical engineering, not search-the-internet-for-me. Have a nice day. And you seem to have a lot of knowledge about wikipedia if it's banned for you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh dear....what Wikipedia does to a man.